# build colorbar based on matplotlib.color.normalize

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, colorbar

I am using matplotlib.colors.Normalize to pick colors for filling patches.

The outline of the code looks as follows:

```
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=max(min_val,1), vmax=max_val) 
mpl_patch = mpl.patches.polygon(item.shape, facecolor=norm(item.value))
plt.gca().add_patch(mpl_patch)
```

The second line is repeated for multiple patches. How can show a colorbar (as separate figure for the color values chosen?

Comment: Did you read [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/colorbar_only.html). What exact problem do you experience?

Comment: that works. thanks.